# json.dumps passes object as a string and not as a json

Tags: python, json, flask

I have a class and a function to change the class object to a json:

```
    class AuthorizedUser:
    def __init__(self, authorized, comsi, given_name, access_role):
        self.authorized = authorized
        self.comsi = comsi
        self.given_name = given_name
        self.access_role = access_role

    def to_json(self):
        return json.dumps(self, default=lambda o: o.__dict__)
```

I have also a json, which works:

```
authorized_user_json = {
        'authorized': authorized_user.authorized,
        'comsi': authorized_user.comsi,
        'given_name': authorized_user.given_name,
        'access_role': authorized_user.access_role
    }
```

Result:

```
{'authorized': True, 'comsi': None, 'given_name': None, 'access_role': 'standard_user'}
```

But when I use:

```
authorized_user_json_ss = authorized_user.to_json()
```

The result is:

```
<SecureCookieSession {'current_user': '{"authorized": true, "comsi": null, "given_name": null, "access_role": "standard_user"}'}>
```

Why do I have additional quotation marks when I use the to_json() function?

Comment: Because if you did not have the "additional quotation" it would have been a dict, not a string? (which it should be, since `json.dumps` returns a string)

Comment: Oh, okay. could you give me a tip for the correct direction what I want to achieve? Obviously I dont want to return a string

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want to achieve. Do you want to convert your object to a dictionary?

Comment: then don't use `dumps`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON is a text representation of unstructured data that makes passing data from one kind of language to another easier.

In Python JSON is merely a dict stored in text.

This is **NOT** JSON, it is a python DICT:

```
authorized_user_json = {
        'authorized': authorized_user.authorized,
        'comsi': authorized_user.comsi,
        'given_name': authorized_user.given_name,
        'access_role': authorized_user.access_role
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I understand!